# How to create GAE app with Editor role

Tags: python, google-app-engine, deployment, google-cloud-platform

I can not create GAE app neither from console or gcloud command with Editor role.

Does anyone know how to create GAE app in Editor role or any solution to create GAE app without owner role?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not possible. Creating GAE apps requires the Owner role. From [Required permissions](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/access-control#required_permissions):

> [apps.create](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/reference/rest/v1/apps/create)
>
> **appengine.applications.create** on the requested [Application](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/reference/rest/v1/apps) resource. Requires [Owner role](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/access-control#primitive_roles) permissions on GCP project.

Also from [Primitive roles](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/access-control#primitive_roles):

> **Owner**
>
> ... Create App Engine applications, deploy application code, update
>   all configurations
>
> **Editor**
>
> ... Deploy application code, update indexes/queues/crons